# How to install a Virtual Machine that runs Ubuntu OS on an AIX machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, aix

I have access to an AIX machine:

```
-bash-3.00$ uname -snlrvmaxupfFM
AIX xxxx 109286105 3 5 00068392D900 powerpc IBM,8204-E8A IBM,036568392 040183749F887601 040183749F887600
```

**How could I install an Ubuntu OS VM on this machine?**

```
-bash-3.00$ oslevel -g
Fileset                                 Actual Level        Maintenance Level
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bos.rte                                 5.3.8.0             5.3.0.0
-bash-3.00$
```

Comment: Which [virtualization technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software) have you already discarded? I don't know how much will it be priced, but I would start trying to find a [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) solution.

Comment: i'm stuck in a lowly tiered job where they say, "here's the machine. where's the code?". They dont even care how 'usable' the machine is to the devs.

Comment: all I'm gonna say is "wtf"

Comment: As I said in [your other question](http://superuser.com/questions/701463/how-to-do-sudo-apt-get-on-an-aix-machine/) you are definitely going to have a very bad time. But as long as [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) supports your PowerPC architecture as host, you may be able (with costs unknown) to virtualize Ubuntu. But you may find a better solution wiping the whole AIX installation and installing [Debian GNU/Linux](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.3.0/powerpc/iso-cd/) instead. But take into account that you may end up with a dead brick.

Comment: For powerpc additional operating systems are usually installed in LPARs (logical partitions). AIX 5.3 is getting old however.